# What is the -lOpenCL on Mac?

Tags: macos, gcc, makefile, opencl

I was trying to `make` an OpenCL demo program, which is using `gcc`. The `-lOpenCL` is available for Ubuntu, but not Mac. What would the counterpart for that on Mac be?

```
ld: library not found for -lOpenCL
```

Answer (score 7):

I have this code lying around on my iMac:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <OpenCL/opencl.h>

int main(int argc, char* const argv[]) {
    cl_uint num_devices, i;
    clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, 0, NULL, &num_devices);

    cl_device_id* devices = calloc(sizeof(cl_device_id), num_devices);
    clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, num_devices, devices, NULL);

    char buf[128];
    for (i = 0; i < num_devices; i++) {
        clGetDeviceInfo(devices[i], CL_DEVICE_NAME, 128, buf, NULL);
        fprintf(stdout, "Device %s supports ", buf);

        clGetDeviceInfo(devices[i], CL_DEVICE_VERSION, 128, buf, NULL);
        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", buf);
    }

    free(devices);
}
```

It compiles with:

```
clang -framework OpenCL hello.c -o hello
```

And when run, gives:

```
Device Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700K CPU @ 4.00GHz supports OpenCL 1.2 
Device AMD Radeon R9 M395 Compute Engine supports OpenCL 1.2
```

---

If you are experimenting with OpenCL, I also used **homebrew** to install `clinfo`, i.e.

```
brew install clinfo
```

And when run, that gives:

```
Number of platforms                               1
  Platform Name                                   Apple
  Platform Vendor                                 Apple
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 1.2 (Mar 15 2018 21:59:37)
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_APPLE_SetMemObjectDestructor cl_APPLE_ContextLoggingFunctions cl_APPLE_clut cl_APPLE_query_kernel_names cl_APPLE_gl_sharing cl_khr_gl_event

  Platform Name                                   Apple
Number of devices                                 2
  Device Name                                     Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700K CPU @ 4.00GHz
  Device Vendor                                   Intel
  Device Vendor ID                                0xffffffff
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 1.2 
  Driver Version                                  1.1
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 1.2 
  Device Type                                     CPU
  Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
  Device Available                                Yes
  Compiler Available                              Yes
  Linker Available                                Yes
  Max compute units                               8
  Max clock frequency                             4000MHz
  Device Partition                                (core)
    Max number of sub-devices                     0
    Supported partition types                     None
  Max work item dimensions                        3
  Max work item sizes                             1024x1x1
  Max work group size                             1024
  Preferred work group size multiple              1
  Preferred / native vector sizes                 
    char                                                16 / 16      
    short                                                8 / 8       
    int                                                  4 / 4       
    long                                                 2 / 2       
    half                                                 0 / 0        (n/a)
    float                                                4 / 4       
    double                                               2 / 2        (cl_khr_fp64)
  Half-precision Floating-point support           (n/a)
  Single-precision Floating-point support         (core)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 Yes
    Round to infinity                             Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               Yes
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  Yes
  Double-precision Floating-point support         (cl_khr_fp64)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 Yes
    Round to infinity                             Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               Yes
    Support is emulated in software               No
  Address bits                                    64, Little-Endian
  Global memory size                              34359738368 (32GiB)
  Error Correction support                        No
  Max memory allocation                           8589934592 (8GiB)
  Unified memory for Host and Device              Yes
  Minimum alignment for any data type             128 bytes
  Alignment of base address                       1024 bits (128 bytes)
  Global Memory cache type                        Read/Write
  Global Memory cache size                        64
  Global Memory cache line size                   8388608 bytes
  Image support                                   Yes
    Max number of samplers per kernel             16
    Max size for 1D images from buffer            65536 pixels
    Max 1D or 2D image array size                 2048 images
    Base address alignment for 2D image buffers   1 bytes
    Pitch alignment for 2D image buffers          1 pixels
    Max 2D image size                             8192x8192 pixels
    Max 3D image size                             2048x2048x2048 pixels
    Max number of read image args                 128
    Max number of write image args                8
  Local memory type                               Global
  Local memory size                               32768 (32KiB)
  Max number of constant args                     8
  Max constant buffer size                        65536 (64KiB)
  Max size of kernel argument                     4096 (4KiB)
  Queue properties                                
    Out-of-order execution                        No
    Profiling                                     Yes
  Prefer user sync for interop                    Yes
  Profiling timer resolution                      1ns
  Execution capabilities                          
    Run OpenCL kernels                            Yes
    Run native kernels                            Yes
  printf() buffer size                            1048576 (1024KiB)
  Built-in kernels                                
  Device Extensions                               cl_APPLE_SetMemObjectDestructor cl_APPLE_ContextLoggingFunctions cl_APPLE_clut cl_APPLE_query_kernel_names cl_APPLE_gl_sharing cl_khr_gl_event cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_int64_base_atomics cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_image2d_from_buffer cl_APPLE_fp64_basic_ops cl_APPLE_fixed_alpha_channel_orders cl_APPLE_biased_fixed_point_image_formats cl_APPLE_command_queue_priority

  Device Name                                     AMD Radeon R9 M395 Compute Engine
  Device Vendor                                   AMD
  Device Vendor ID                                0x1021c00
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 1.2 
  Driver Version                                  1.2 (Mar 15 2018 21:59:57)
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 1.2 
  Device Type                                     GPU
  Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
  Device Available                                Yes
  Compiler Available                              Yes
  Linker Available                                Yes
  Max compute units                               28
  Max clock frequency                             834MHz
  Device Partition                                (core)
    Max number of sub-devices                     0
    Supported partition types                     None
  Max work item dimensions                        3
  Max work item sizes                             256x256x256
  Max work group size                             256
  Preferred work group size multiple              64
  Preferred / native vector sizes                 
    char                                                 4 / 4       
    short                                                2 / 2       
    int                                                  1 / 1       
    long                                                 1 / 1       
    half                                                 0 / 0        (n/a)
    float                                                1 / 1       
    double                                               1 / 1        (cl_khr_fp64)
  Half-precision Floating-point support           (n/a)
  Single-precision Floating-point support         (core)
    Denormals                                     No
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 Yes
    Round to infinity                             Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               No
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  Yes
  Double-precision Floating-point support         (cl_khr_fp64)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 Yes
    Round to infinity                             Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               Yes
    Support is emulated in software               No
  Address bits                                    32, Little-Endian
  Global memory size                              2147483648 (2GiB)
  Error Correction support                        No
  Max memory allocation                           536870912 (512MiB)
  Unified memory for Host and Device              No
  Minimum alignment for any data type             128 bytes
  Alignment of base address                       32768 bits (4096 bytes)
  Global Memory cache type                        None
  Image support                                   Yes
    Max number of samplers per kernel             16
    Max size for 1D images from buffer            65536 pixels
    Max 1D or 2D image array size                 2048 images
    Base address alignment for 2D image buffers   256 bytes
    Pitch alignment for 2D image buffers          256 pixels
    Max 2D image size                             16384x16384 pixels
    Max 3D image size                             2048x2048x2048 pixels
    Max number of read image args                 128
    Max number of write image args                8
  Local memory type                               Local
  Local memory size                               32768 (32KiB)
  Max number of constant args                     8
  Max constant buffer size                        65536 (64KiB)
  Max size of kernel argument                     1024
  Queue properties                                
    Out-of-order execution                        No
    Profiling                                     Yes
  Prefer user sync for interop                    Yes
  Profiling timer resolution                      37ns
  Execution capabilities                          
    Run OpenCL kernels                            Yes
    Run native kernels                            No
  printf() buffer size                            134217728 (128MiB)
  Built-in kernels                                
  Device Extensions                               cl_APPLE_SetMemObjectDestructor cl_APPLE_ContextLoggingFunctions cl_APPLE_clut cl_APPLE_query_kernel_names cl_APPLE_gl_sharing cl_khr_gl_event cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_image2d_from_buffer cl_khr_depth_images cl_APPLE_command_queue_priority cl_APPLE_command_queue_select_compute_units cl_khr_fp64

NULL platform behavior
  clGetPlatformInfo(NULL, CL_PLATFORM_NAME, ...)  Apple
  clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, ...)   Success [P0]
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [default]            Success [P0]
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT)  Success (1)
    Platform Name                                 Apple
    Device Name                                   AMD Radeon R9 M395 Compute Engine
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU)  Success (1)
    Platform Name                                 Apple
    Device Name                                   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700K CPU @ 4.00GHz
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU)  Success (1)
    Platform Name                                 Apple
    Device Name                                   AMD Radeon R9 M395 Compute Engine
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CUSTOM)  <checkNullCtxFromType:2580: create context from type CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CUSTOM : error -30>
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL)  Success (2)
    Platform Name                                 Apple
    Device Name                                   AMD Radeon R9 M395 Compute Engine
    Device Name                                   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700K CPU @ 4.00GHz
    NOTE:   your OpenCL library only supports OpenCL 1.0,
        but some installed platforms support OpenCL 1.2.
        Programs using 1.2 features may crash
        or behave unexepectedly
```

Comment: Thanks for the demo `main()`! I figured that I can add OpenCL.framework to .xcodeproj as well.

Comment: One question about the `main()` is `calloc` does not return any value, does it? I am seeing this error in Xcode: `Cannot initialize a variable of type 'cl_device_id *' (aka '_cl_device_id **') with an rvalue of type 'void *'`.

Comment: Ummm! I am no expert on OpenCL. You tagged with `gcc` and the code is `C` rather than `C++` so maybe you need to name it and compile accordingly... just checking myself too in Xcode. It works in my `Xcode` if named `simple.c`.

Comment: Sorry my bad... I was modifying an existing project and forgot to switch to C. It works now after renaming to `.c`! Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @MarkSetchell Great tip about `clinfo` - triggered a `dyld: Symbol not found: _CGLGetCurrentContext` that I had been trying to pin down and this is helping me to isolate the problem. Thanks!